# Composition of an $L^{\infty}$ function with an homeomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ supposed convex with smooth boundary. Let $f\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and let $\varphi\in Id+W_{0}^{1,\infty}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^2)$ be an homeomorphism from $\bar{\Omega}$ to $\bar{\Omega}$ such that $\forall q>2$, $\varphi^{-1}$ is in $W^{1,q}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^2)$.
Is $f \circ \varphi^{-1}\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$? If yes, is it true that
$\|f \circ \varphi^{-1}\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}\leq \|f\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}$?
I do thank you for your attention. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $N\subset \Omega$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M:= \|f\|_{L^\infty}$ for every $x\in \Omega\setminus N$ and $|N|=0$. Let $N':=\varphi(N)$, then we have

1. $|N'|=0$.
2. $|f\circ\varphi^{-1}(y)|\leq M$ for every $y\notin N'$.

1 follows from the fact that Lipschitz maps decrease Lebesgue measure (or more generally any Hausdorff measure), i.e. $|\varphi(A)|\leq \| \varphi\|_{Lip}|A|$ for every set $A$. On the other hand, if $y\notin N'$, then $y=\varphi(x)$ for some $x\notin N$ and so $f\circ \varphi^{-1}(y)= f(x)$ and the claim follows from the definition of $N$.

It seems to me that the extra assumptions on $\varphi^{-1}$ are not needed, but maybe I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Many thanks for your very clear answer. (In my problem, Ball's theorem on global invertibility ensures that  $\varphi^{-1}\in W^{1,q}(Ω,\mathbb{R}^2)$ for all $q>2$ but it is useless here indeed).  Just to be sure, we can in fact conclude that $\|f \circ \varphi^{-1}\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}=\|f\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}$. I am sorry if it is obvious. I do thank you and don't bother you again. Best wishes.

Comment: @C.G.: No worries, it's an interesting question! The equality holds, since $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism (so that we take on exactly the same values as $f$ outside of $N'$).

Comment: I am very grateful to you! Best wishes.

Comment: @C.G. One quick clarification: My last statement is wrong; equality need not hold under these hypotheses (or at the very least it's not because of the reasons I stated). The issue is that while $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism, it's not necessarily true that $\varphi(A)$ has measure zero if and only if $A$ does; so potentially it could happen that while we do take on the same values, some large set gets squished into a null set, possibly decreasing the $L^\infty$ norm (notice that the extra conditions of $\varphi^{-1}$ guarantee that it's in $C^\alpha$ for every $\alpha<1$, --

Comment: --but this is not good enough to guarantee that measure zero sets get mapped to measure zero sets, as is the case of $\varphi$ being Lipschitz.

Comment: Many thanks for your clarification. Measure theory is not my forte. It seems that in my problem I can recover that $\varphi^{-1}$ is Lipschitz continuous. In this case, the equality holds? Best wishes. Carole

Comment: @C.G. Yes, if you know that $\varphi^{-1}$ is Lipschitz continuous then you do have $|\varphi(A)|=0$ if and only if $|A|=0$ and then equality should hold as far as I can tell.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. I believe that we can apply the same reasoning as the one you made in your answer " Jul 20 at 7:48" to $f\circ \varphi^{-1}$ composed to the right with $\varphi$. In this case, we obtain that $\|f\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \leq \|f\circ \varphi^{-1}\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}$ and then equality holds.

Comment: Can you just tell me if you agree with my last comment? I do thank you very much for your help. Best wishes.

Comment: @C.G.: I agree, if you have $\varphi$ Lipschitz, then your comment is correct.

Comment: Many thanks for your precious help. Best wishes.